# IPython run script from breakpoint or line number

Tags: ipython

I use the magic function `%run` often. Is there a way to run a script from a given line number or from some other label?

Example use:
I edit my script in an editor and use `%run` in IPython. I usually need to modify how I'm visualizing some data that I compute in the beginning of the script, but I don't need to recompute it each time. (I know I can cache the data in a file, or refactor my code; that's not the answer I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/htmlnotebook.html). It lets you write chunks of code and run them at any time on your interactive namespace.

[Here's a demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaS4NXxL5Qc&feature=player_embedded)

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the part you don't want to run, and in ipython you can run with : run -i ,which run with all the current variables.